# How can I use codehilite and mermaid together?

Tags: mkdocs, mermaid

We generate documentation using mkdocs with the material theme and until now have used the codehilite extension. I've now added mermaid using a method described here: https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/issues/693

First, my markdown:

````
# Examples

## Mermaid
```mermaid
graph LR
    a[Start] -- b[(Storage)]-->d[End]
```
## Code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tensorflow as tf
```
````

My mkdocs.yml:

```
# Project information
site_name: Test
site_description: 'Mermaid with CodeHiLite'

theme:
   name: material
   feature:
      tabs: false

extra_javascript:
   - 'custom_content/mermaid.min.js'

markdown_extensions:
   - codehilite
```

In this configuration the mermaid code is not rendered as a diagramm but the code is syntax highlighted.

[image: Codehilite]

If I extend my mkdocs.yml to add mermaid like this:

```
# Project information
site_name: Test
site_description: 'Mermaid with CodeHiLite'
theme:
   name: material
   feature:
      tabs: false

extra_javascript:
   - 'custom_content/mermaid.min.js'

markdown_extensions:
   - codehilite
   - pymdownx.superfences:
       custom_fences:
         - name: mermaid
           class: mermaid
           format: !!python/name:pymdownx.superfences.fence_div_format
```

then the mermaid diagrams are rendered properly but the code is not syntax highlighted.

[image: Mermaid]

If I change the markdown to add the language to the code block

````
``` python
#!/usr/bin/python
import tensorflow as tf
```
````

then both code and diagram are rendered correctly. The problem I have is that the existing documentation doesn't specify a language and until now that worked.

Any ideas how to get these two extensions to work together better? Or am I just going to have to tell the developers to update their markdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a prepackaged solution to integrate mermaid diagrams into mkdocs, there is now the [mkdocs-mermaid2](https://github.com/fralau/mkdocs-mermaid2-plugin) plugin, which I'm maintaining.

For code highlighting, it also contains an example of how to make it work with the [superfences](https://facelessuser.github.io/pymdown-extensions/extensions/superfences/) plugin.

It may be especially useful if one needs to [pass arguments](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/Setup?id=mermaidapi-configuration-defaults) to the `initialize()` method of the mermaid renderer, to tweak the look of diagrams.